# Is Elide library Miscroservice architecture friendly?

Tags: spring-boot, graph, json-api

I notice that [Elide](https://elide.io/) expose GraphQL and JSON API at the same time. So from microservices point of view only one technology will be used at a time. It looks like a lot of resources will be wasted. From my point of view Elide looks like library for Monolithic architecture, it was not desinged for microservices. So is it possible to exclude some features from this library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Elide has customizable properties (if you're using the Spring Boot Starter). In `application.yml` you have these properties:

```yaml
elide:
  modelPackage: 'com.my_app.model'
  json-api:
    path: ${server.servlet.context-path}/api/v1
    enabled: true
  graphql:
    path: /graphql/api/v1
    enabled: true
  swagger:
    path: /doc
    enabled: true
  subscription:
    enabled: false
```

In addition, you have to manually edit the `index.html` that's in the 'resources/META-INF/resources' folder and remove the links to the Swagger doc or Graphiql (depending on which one you want to remove)